# How to know the size of a page for data transfer calculations

Tags: html, amazon-web-services, web-hosting

I'm trying to calculate the total number of Giabytes that my website will need for outbound data transfer before deciding whether I will host in AWS or other hosting companies, since AWS only provide a monthly free limit of 15 GB outbound. I need to know the size of a page visit, and then will multiply this by the total number of visits per month. I'm still having my website as a localhost, so I couldn't use the online tools yet. I tried to use "Save as" which downloaded the page along with all CSS files and images, so could this be an accurate size of a page ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3437786/get-the-size-of-the-screen-current-web-page-and-browser-window

Comment: open the 'Network' tab in browser 'developer tools' by pressing f12..... it will show you the sizes.... of each request... per page, you can then add them all up, i believe it does this for you anyway.... disable cache.. if you want it to show with out anything being cache on future requests... or previous

Comment: I can see MB transferred and Resources. Which one should I refer to ?